# How can I check if a value exists in mySQL database table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I simply want to check if a value exists in my mySQL database table:

```
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM farm WHERE animal = 'horse'";

    if ($sql == 0) {
        echo 'animal does not exist<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'animal does exist<br>';
    };

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo($row['animal'].'<br>');
    }
    Database::disconnect();
```

But my result is:

```
animal does not exists
Horse
```

So there must be a mistake because obviously my horse exists.

Comment: Read some PDO tutorials. You check if `"SELECT * FROM farm WHERE animal = 'horse'" ==0` not the rowcount of the result.

Comment: Thank you, I searched in a tutorial and found this `$rowcount=$sql->rowCount(); if ($rowcount == 0) {...`I will give it a try

Comment: @Jarla yeah, but that's not the point. the point is that in your line `$sql = "SELECT * FROM farm WHERE animal = 'horse'";` you have just a variable set to a string, nothing else. there is no database interaction. you need to `query` first (for example with `$pdo->query()`) before there is anything done with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First execute the select statement,

$dbh=db connection ....

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM farm WHERE animal = 'horse'");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'animal does not exist<br>';
} else {
    echo 'animal does exist<br>';
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rowCount()`([PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)) to check it..

```
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo ($row_count > 0) ? 'exists' : ' not exists';
```

Comment: this should work for you, Jarla. and make sure you understand that `$stmt` is a `object` of the type "statement" here, because PDO's `query` returns a "statement". you can't use `$sql->rowCount()` when `$sql` contains just a string.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer imho. it's more simple, more accurate and makes use of PDO's built-in functions which exactly fit to the problem in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM farm WHERE animal = 'horse'";
$data = $pdo->query($sql);
if ($data == 0) {
    echo 'animal does not exist<br>';
} else {
    echo 'animal does exist<br>';
};

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo($row['animal'].'<br>');
}
Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: You execute th query twice. That is not good for the performance.

Comment: Thank you! This works fine, I see what was the problem

Comment: sorry I made a test with 'duck' and the result is now still `animal does exist`. But there is no duck in my database :(